# Apache ProxyPass and errors

Tags: apache, proxy, glassfish

I have two ProxyPass directives:

```
ProxyPass /client/ http://10.0.0.8:8080/client/
<Location /client/>
    RequestHeader edit X-GWT-Module-Base ^(.*)/client/(.*)$ $1/client/$2
</Location>

ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.8:8080/client/
<Location />
    RequestHeader edit X-GWT-Module-Base ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1/client/$2
</Location>
```

`10.0.0.8` is running Glassfish on port 8080 and `http://10.0.0.8:8080/client/` is URL to a GWT based application.
Both proxy's work OK ,except when it comes to an error on the Glassfish side.
If I go via /cllient/ proxy then I see the actual error that was produced on the Glassfish side. If I go via / proxy then I only see "Error 500 The call failed on the server, please see server log". I've tried setting `ProxyErrorOverride Off`, but it didn't help.

Why don't I see the error via / proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/2P15JslejXg/dldFRN_pIeEJ

is the approach I'm using now and it works:

```
ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.8:8080/myGWTApp/    
<Location />
    RequestHeader edit X-GWT-Module-Base ^(http)://([^/]+)/(.*)$ $1://$2/myGWTApp/$3
</Location>
```